# SQL - Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: sql

I'm running my query using a stored procedure, but I get an error. I want to update every column per `TicketNumber`. I'm updating my `TimeRun` column which to calculate the current running time. `DateAndTime` is my start date which the day was created calculated with my variable `@end` which the current time.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spTicketTimeUpdate
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @start DATETIME, @end DATETIME = GETDATE(),
            @runningTime VARCHAR(50), @x INT

    SET @start = (SELECT DateAndTime FROM TicketTb)
    SET @x = DATEDIFF(s, @start, @end);

    SET @runningTime = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (@x / 86400)) + ' Day(s) ' +
                       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ((@x % 86400) / 3600)) + ' Hr(s) ' +
                       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (((@x % 86400) % 3600) / 60)) + ' Min(s) ' + 
                       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), (((@x % 86400) % 3600) % 60)) + ' Sec(s)';

    UPDATE TicketTb 
    SET TimeRun = @runningTime 
    WHERE TicketStatus = 'Open'

    UPDATE TicketTb 
    SET RunTimeClose = @runningTime

END
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you want to look into UPDATE... FROM and JOIN the table to itself. Does `TicketTb` have a PrimaryKey?

Comment: Yes. "Tid" the name of my column. yes, you said it right. i want to update on my TimeRun Column but based on my Date Created. which my column to be start date to be calculated is "DateAndTime:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spTicketTimeUpdate

as
begin

declare @end datetime
set @end = getdate()

update TicketTb set TimeRun = t1.rt 
from
    (select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( DATEDIFF(s, DateAndTime, @end) / 86400 )) + ' Day(s) '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( ( DATEDIFF(s, DateAndTime, @end) % 86400 ) / 3600 )) + ' Hr(s) '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( ( ( DATEDIFF(s, DateAndTime, @end) % 86400 ) % 3600 ) / 60 ))
        + ' Min(s) ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( ( ( DATEDIFF(s, DateAndTime, @end) % 86400 ) % 3600 ) % 60 ))
        + ' Sec(s)' as rt, TicketNumber from TicketTb
            where TicketStatus = 'Open') as t1
where t1.TicketNumber = TicketTb.TicketNumber


update TicketTb set RunTimeClose = t1.rt 
from
    (select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( DATEDIFF(s, DateAndTime, @end) / 86400 )) + ' Day(s) '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( ( DATEDIFF(s, DateAndTime, @end) % 86400 ) / 3600 )) + ' Hr(s) '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( ( ( DATEDIFF(s, DateAndTime, @end) % 86400 ) % 3600 ) / 60 ))
        + ' Min(s) ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( ( ( DATEDIFF(s, DateAndTime, @end) % 86400 ) % 3600 ) % 60 ))
        + ' Sec(s)' as rt, TicketNumber from TicketTb
            ) as t1
where t1.TicketNumber = TicketTb.TicketNumber
```

end

Comment: it works , but the result is all of my TimeRun Column is the same because it only getting the top, which supposed to be depend on my TicketNumber column

Comment: seems you are trying to update the column based on ticketnumber, i updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [Metals excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57847628/4665), this can be done in one query with the [CASE Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spTicketTimeUpdate

as
begin

declare @end datetime
set @end = getdate()


update TicketTb set RunTimeClose = t1.rt ,
                    TimeRun = CASE
                                 WHERE TicketTb.TicketStatus = 'Open' Then t1.rt
                                 ELSE  TimeRun
                               END CASE
from
    (select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( DATEDIFF(s, DateAndTime, @end) / 86400 )) + ' Day(s) '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( ( DATEDIFF(s, DateAndTime, @end) % 86400 ) / 3600 )) + ' Hr(s) '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( ( ( DATEDIFF(s, DateAndTime, @end) % 86400 ) % 3600 ) / 60 ))
        + ' Min(s) ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( ( ( DATEDIFF(s, DateAndTime, @end) % 86400 ) % 3600 ) % 60 ))
        + ' Sec(s)' as rt, TicketNumber from TicketTb
            ) as t1
where t1.TicketNumber = TicketTb.TicketNumber

Close
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this. To simplify this i divided this query in different section using `cte`. First you'll get the difference of time as you need in `@x` then you'll calculate your time difference in string in `ct` section. At the end by using case statement you may update both of your result in single update query as follows.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spTicketTimeUpdate

as
begin

;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT TicketNumber, TicketStatus, DateAndTime, DATEDIFF(S, DateAndTime, GETDATE()) AS DIFF FROM TicketTb )
, CT AS (
SELECT TicketNumber, TicketStatus, DateAndTime, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( DIFF / 86400 )) + ' Day(s) '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( ( DIFF  % 86400 ) / 3600 )) + ' Hr(s) '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( ( ( DIFF  % 86400 ) % 3600 ) / 60 ))
        + ' Min(s) ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( ( ( DIFF  % 86400 ) % 3600 ) % 60 ))
        + ' Sec(s)' AS DIFFINSEC 
FROM CTE)
UPDATE T SET T.RunTimeClose = C.DIFFINSEC, 
       T.TimeRun = (CASE WHEN T.TicketStatus = 'Open' THEN C.DIFFINSEC ELSE C.TicketStatus )
FROM TicketTb AS T INNER JOIN CT AS C ON T.TicketNumber = C.TicketNumber AND T.TicketStatus=C.TicketStatus

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this line:

```
set  @start = (Select DateAndTime from TicketTb)
```

If the table `TicketTb` has more than one row, the engine doesn't know which row to pick.

You should decide how to pick one row yourself, something like this:

```
set  @start = (Select TOP(1) DateAndTime from TicketTb order by DateAndTime DESC)
```

Comment: it works , but the result is all of my TimeRun Column is the same because it only getting the top, which supposed to be depend on my TicketNumber column